# Replace first occurrence of substring in a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to fetch data from a @temp table which has something like "or ccc or bbb or aaa" I want to replace the first occurrence into space to get something like this " ccc or bbb or aaa". I am trying stuff and replace but they don't seem to get me the desired result

What I have tried:

```
DECLARE @stringhere as varchar(500)

DECLARE @stringtofind as varchar(500)

set @stringhere='OR contains or cccc or  '

set @stringtofind='or'
select STUFF('OR contains or cccc or  ',PATINDEX('or', 'OR contains or cccc or  '),0 ,' ')
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a where clause for a dynamic query?

Comment: i am trying to get a final value after removing the first occurrence of a string..

Comment: Please [read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about urgent begging, and be informed that this is not an appropriate way to address volunteers. Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use a combination of `STUFF` and `CHARINDEX` to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT STUFF(col, CHARINDEX('substring', col), LEN('substring'), 'replacement')
FROM #temp
```

`CHARINDEX('substring', col)` will return the index of the *first* occurrence of `'substring'` in the column.  `STUFF` then replaces this occurrence with `'replacement'`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, worked absolutely fine... searched hours for this got no good enough result. ... Thank you

Comment: Glad to help you ... and you asked a pretty good question :-)

Comment: Bit late (but surprised this wasn't noted before), but this only seems to work if there *is* an occurrence of `'substring'`. If there isn't, `null` is returned. So a `CASE` expression to catch that is advisable.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Nice catch.  Or, we could just wrap the entire call to `STUFF` inside `COALESCE`, and replace null values with the original column.

Comment: This has an issue with collations though: The matching substring may have a different length than the search string ('hä' is in 'haegar' in German_PhoneBook_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8).

Answer (score 3):

it seems you miss 2`%` preceding and trailing to the target string

please try:

```
select STUFF(@stringhere, PATINDEX('%' + @stringtofind + '%', @stringhere), LEN(@stringtofind), ' ')
```

Comment: @user3331798 : please try

Comment: @user3331798 : Thanks, but why there are 2 single quotes in `'''OR contains or cccc or  '`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `CHARINDEX` or a `PATINDEX`, as shown above, but I would also recommend adding a `COALESCE`, in case your `@stringtoFind` it not included in your `@stringhere`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(STUFF(@stringhere, PATINDEX('%' + @stringtofind + '%', @stringhere), LEN(@stringtofind), ' '), @stringhere)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and made the same response as Tim Biegeleisen, but in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.FN_REPLACE_FIRST(@X NVARCHAR(MAX), @F NVARCHAR(MAX), @R NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN
RETURN STUFF(@X, CHARINDEX(@F, @X), LEN(@F), @R)
END
```

So I just call the function instead:

```
SELECT DBO.FN_REPLACE_FIRST('Text example', 'ex', 'eexx') --> Returns 'Teexxt example'
```

The explanation is the same

Answer (score 0):

To modify only the first letters add a `"WHEN CHARINDEX(@FindText, @Text) = 1"`
If not, you risk replacing another letter in your sentence if it is not present.

```
DECLARE 
    @Text varchar(MAX),
    @TextReplaceBy varchar(20),
    @FindText varchar(20);

SET @Text = 'Text to replace';
SET @FindText = 't';
SET @TextReplaceBy = '';
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX(@FindText, @Text) = 1
      THEN STUFF(@Text, CHARINDEX(@FindText, @Text), LEN(@FindText), @TextReplaceBy) 
    ELSE @Text
END
```