# SQL: Replacing only the first of a certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to replace the first of a certain character in my SQL query.
In my case I'm trying to replace the first " - " by a " ; ", but not the second

This is a simplified version of the query i've tried, but it replaces both "-"

`SELECT REPLACE (xColumn, '-',';')FROM xTable`

**Example 1:**

Original data: *COMP-LAP-0001*

My result: *COMP;LAP;0001*

Expected result: *COMP;LAP-0001*

**Example 2:**

Original data: *COMP-0001*

My result: *COMP;0001*

Expected result: *COMP;0001*

Comment: [Replace first occurrence of substring in a string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911588/replace-first-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string-in-sql#38911646)

Comment: Thank You @LukaszSzozda but this will cause the result to be trancated? my result can't be cut off after the " - "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX()` to locate the first occurence of the given character in the string, and then replace it with `STUFF()`:

```
SELECT STUFF(xColumn, CHARINDEX('-', xColumn), 1, ';') FROM xTable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36a2dd823d61fe3ad626460f54407895)**:

```
WITH xTable AS (
    SELECT 'COMP-LAP-0001' xColumn
    UNION ALL SELECT 'COMP-0001'
)
SELECT STUFF(xColumn, CHARINDEX('-', xColumn), 1, ';') FROM xTable
```

```
| (No column name) |
| :--------------- |
| COMP;LAP-0001    |
| COMP;0001        |
```

Comment: This will truncate the output after replacing the first - with ;. Instead of LEN(xColumn) it should be 1.

Comment: I don't want the result to be trancated, i just need to replace the first " - " with a " ; " without losing any other characters

Comment: @SeanLange: yes you are right, I fixed the query (and added a DB Fiddle). Thank you.

Comment: This now works exactly as the OP is looking for. +1

Comment: Thanks @GMB but I have 4000+ data in that column they don't all start and end with the same characters. Example of the data i have ORDI-09912, ABC-CBA-3234, ACER192. Will this query give me the expected results?

Comment: You need to use the query in the select statement and replace your table and columns with your proper names. This is an example using a cte as way to have a table to select from.

Comment: @ChristopherBoisvert: this should work as expected. You can play around and test the query in the db fiddle link that I provided in the answer. Let me know if something is not working as intended.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the edited query, this new query works! Just needed to add a ISNULL for the results that didn't include " - ". Thanks!

Comment: And thanks to @SeanLange for following up on the thread!