# Want to know how to remove space among words in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how to remove space between first and second word. But it should not remove other spaces in the same column. (Using SQL)
It looks like this,

```
No. 378, Bearly Road, Colombo.
```

I want to remove only the space between "No." and "378". After remove it should be like this,

```
No.378, Bearly Road, Colombo.
```

Comment: If you want to do it in SQL why did you tag Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace first occurrence of substring in a string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911588/replace-first-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`String::replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) (assuming you're doing this in Java).

```java
str.replaceFirst(" ", "");
```

For SQL-Server check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911588/replace-first-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string-in-sql).

Comment: @DaleK This answer is using Java, possibly because the Java tag appears under the question.  It probably assumes that the data came from SQL, but the replacement is wanted for Java.

Comment: *remove only the space between "No." and "378".* - your answer will ignore this requirement

Comment: Any idea doing this using sql??

Comment: @chriptus13 rather than linking to an existing answer, please vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT STUFF('No. 1', CHARINDEX(' ', 'No. 1'), 1, '')
                    (or)
SELECT concat(left('No. 1',CHARINDEX(' ','No. 1')-1),substring('No. 1',CHARINDEX(' ','No. 1')+1,len('No. 1')))
```